# How can i bind objects field to text box?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

Model:

```
public class DishesModel
{
    public Dish DishToAdd{get; set;}
    public List<Dish> AllDishes{get; set;}
    public List<Category> AllCategories{get; set;}
    public List<Dish> SelectedDishes{get; set;}

    public DishesModel()
    {
        DishToAdd = new Dish();
    }

    public void AddDish()
    {
        if(DishToAdd!=null && !AllDishes.Contains(DishToAdd))
        {
            AllDishes.Add(DishToAdd);
            DishToAdd = null;
        }
    }

    public void RemoveSelected()
    {
        AllDishes.RemoveAll(d=>SelectedDishes.Any(m=>m.Name==d.Name));
        SelectedDishes.Clear();
    }

    public void SortDishes()
    {
        AllDishes.Sort();
    }

}

public class Dish:BaseEntity<Int32>
{
    public virtual String Name{get; set;}
    public virtual Decimal Price{get; set;}
    public virtual String Description{get; set;}
    public virtual IList<Category> Categories{get; set;}
    public virtual IList<Complex> Complexs{ get; set;}
}
```

Razor:

```
 @{
    KnockoutContext<MyMenu.Models.DishesModel> ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "title";
}

<h2>Work with dishes.</h2>
@using(ko.Html.Form("AddDish", "Dishes", null, new{id="formDishes"}))
{
    @ko.Html.ListBox(m => m.AllDishes, new {size = 15}, dish => dish.Name).SelectedOptions(m=>m.SelectedDishes)
    @ko.Html.Button("Remove", "Remove", "Dishes").Enable(m => m.SelectedDishes.Count > 0)
    @ko.Html.Button("Sort", "Sort", "Dishes").Enable(m => m.AllDishes.Count > 1)
         <span>Name</span>         @ko.Html.TextBox(m=>m.DishToAdd.Name).ValueUpdate(KnockoutValueUpdateKind.KeyPress)
         <span>Price</span>
         @ko.Html.TextBox(m =>m.DishToAdd.Price).ValueUpdate(KnockoutValueUpdateKind.KeyPress)
         <span>Description</span>
         @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.DishToAdd.Description).ValueUpdate(KnockoutValueUpdateKind.KeyPress)
         <button type="submit" @ko.Bind.Enable(m => m.DishToAdd.Name.Length > 0)>Add</button>

}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#formDishes').ajaxForm();
</script>

@ko.Apply(Model)
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult AddDish(DishesModel model)
    {
        model.AddDish();
        return Json(model);
    }
```

**Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: object is not a function;
Bindings value: value : DishToAdd().Name,valueUpdate : 'keypress' knockout-2.2.0.js:5**

How can I bind `DishToAdd.Name` to TextBox?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try to typecast the object with string data type

Comment: decision   `using(var subModel=ko.With(m=>m.DishToAdd))
    {
         <span>Name</span>
         @subModel.Html.TextBox(m=>m.Name).ValueUpdate(KnockoutValueUpdateKind.KeyPress)
         <span>Price</span>
         @subModel.Html.TextBox(m =>m.Price).ValueUpdate(KnockoutValueUpdateKind.KeyPress)
         <span>Description</span>
         @subModel.Html.TextBox(m => m.Description).ValueUpdate(KnockoutValueUpdateKind.KeyPress)
         <button type="submit" @subModel.Bind.Enable(m => m.Name.Length > 0)>Add</button>
    }`